# how to change the parameter names "title", "start" and "end" in the fullcalendar jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

In jquery's fullcalendar script I'd like to change the keywords "title" "start" and "end" by the column names that are in my database table.

the fullcalendar work when i change in the database table the name of the colums :

i changed "name" by "title" , "date_start" by "start and "date_end" by "end", ok it's work ,but I would like to do the opposite.

````
                        $(document).ready(function() {

                            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                                editable: false,
                                events: "{{ route('products') }}",
                                displayEventTime: false,
                                eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
                                    if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                                        event.allDay = true;
                                    } else {
                                        event.allDay = false;
                                    }
                                },
                                eventClick: function(event) {

                                    $.getJSON("{{ route('products') }}", function(user) {
                                        var convertToTableau = Array.from(Object.values(user));
                                        console.log(convertToTableau);
                                        var us = $.grep(convertToTableau, function(v) {


                                            return v.id == event.id;
                                            console.log(event.id);

                                        });
                                        $("#firstname").text(us[0].title);
                                        $("#idpilote").text(" Id : " + us[0].id);
                                        $("#firstname").text(" Name : " + us[0].title);
                                        $("#metier").text(" Job : " + us[0].profession);
                                    });
                                }

                            });
                        });
                    </script> ```
````

Comment: So you are updating column names in the table to "title", "start", etc?

Comment: hi Patel, fullcalendar only serves me to display names in the calendar, plus some info (clickkevent). I do not need to insert in the data table using fullcalendar (I insert them via a csv)

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: Are you facing the issue while inserting data into a table or displaying data on the calendar from the table?

Comment: It seems that you are using older version of FullCalendar. I suggest to use updated version if you can, read docs here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs

Comment: It is not recommended by many to try to change the default naming, it may not even possible to do so. Please elaborate your code, it seems it is not completed as per your question

Comment: thank , I take a look at the latest version of fullcalendar

Answer (score 4):

You can't change what fullCalendar [expects](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object) as the default property names for the important fields in your events (well, you could, if you modified the fullCalendar source code, but you don't want to do that).

However, if for some reason you don't want to change your server/database code to match (but why not, exactly??) you can create a simple mapping between the two via the [eventDataTransform](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventDataTransform) callback in fullCalendar. This function runs once for every event which is loaded into fullCalendar, and allows you to update the properties of the event object before fullCalendar starts processing it. In here you can copy data from the server-generated property names to the ones which fullCalendar recognises.

Here's an example:

```
eventDataTransform: function(event) {
  event.title = event.name;
  event.start = event.date_start;
  event.end = event.date_end;
  return event;
}
```

Comment: finally i think it's better to keep the default property names of fullcalendar. I'm going to change the column names of the database table to match the fullcalendar fields ("title," start "," end ").
I wanted to do this because someone asked me at the last minute to graft a calendar to data from a table that had already been made. Fortunately the site is still in development. Thank Dyson ,Patel and Ishaque for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Please try to implement ADyson idea. It seems better approach in your scenario.